# Show/Hide img elements based on input (search bar) value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I've got a photo gallery grid and want to be able to search an img tag's 'data-title' value and only show images that have matching data. So if I types in "hay" the image below would be shown, but all images on the site without "hay" in their data-title would be hidden.

```
<a href="photo_gallery\photos\01.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title
 ="Hay Bales - I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the 
 countryside past some straw fields.">
    <img src="photo_gallery\photos\thumbnails\01.jpg" alt="fields">
</a>
```

I modified some code I found on here about how to hide divs but can't quite get it to work for searching the data-title attribute. If I type anything into the search box, it hides every image, regardless of that data-title attr.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp(value);

    $('a').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('a[data-title='+value+']', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

Where am I going wrong here? This is how the search bar is set up as well.

```
 <div class="searchBar">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your anchor tags have no text nodes using the JQuery **.text()** method will cause your values to be tested against an empty string. Instead, target the element's data attribute and use that as the subject of your regular expression test.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp(value);

    $('a').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($(this).data('title'));
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! : )

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer would be to remove the `RegExp` entirely since you are using and html5 data set, you can just compare the values directly if you want.

Something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/edh4131/pq3k5zdo/2/